# Correct ratio of slider value when boundary changes

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I am creating slider that keeps the ratio of current value when ever maximum or minimum value changes.

Here is the picture that shows how I am correcting ratio of value on slider.

[image]

*(The second slider is expanded to better explain the solution. Obviously the size of slider in application view is fixed and only values are internally changed.)*

This is what you see as a result.

[image]

The formula I'm using to fix the ratio is pretty simple. This is the formula used when `Maximum` value is changed :

```
NewValue = OldValue * ((newMaximum - Minimum) / (oldMaximum - Minimum));
```

And in case `Minimum` Value is changed :

```
NewValue = OldValue * ((Maximum - newMinimum) / (Maximum - oldMinimum));
```

*(there are few things to consider for example preventing division by zero. but that's off-topic here.)*

Now see when the problem arises. Assume that `newMaximum` is smaller than value of slider. *unfortunately* slider internal behavior wants to correct  the value by doing `value = newMaximum` and therefor this conflicts with my calculations.

The following image shows the problem by doing the reverse. The second slider is what I want but I get third slider.

[image]

---

This is what I've tried. (The code is simplified)

```
protected override void OnMaximumChanged(double oldMaximum, double newMaximum)
{
    if ((oldMaximum - Minimum) <= 0) oldMaximum = Minimum + 1; // prevent 0-division

    Value *= (newMaximum - Minimum) / (oldMaximum - Minimum);

    base.OnMaximumChanged(oldMaximum, newMaximum);
}

protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
{
    //base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
}
```

Even though I'm overriding `OnValueChanged` but slider keeps correcting the value when `newMaximum` is smaller than `value` by doing `value = newMaximum` as you can see in the image. **How can I fix that?**

---

**Warning:** the following code may give you headache! I tried to explain the problem and I hope you understand. in case you want to know more information here is complete `OnMaximumChanged` code that i currently have.

```
private bool _selfChanging;

protected override void OnMaximumChanged(double oldMaximum, double newMaximum)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        if (_selfChanging) return;
        _selfChanging = true;

        if (newMaximum < Minimum)
        {
            IsDirectionReversed = !IsDirectionReversed;

            Maximum = Minimum;
            newMaximum = Maximum;
            Minimum = newMaximum;
        }

        if ((oldMaximum - Minimum) <= 0) oldMaximum = Minimum + 1;

        Value *= (newMaximum - Minimum) / (oldMaximum - Minimum);

        base.OnMaximumChanged(oldMaximum, newMaximum);

        _selfChanging = false;
    }
}

protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
{
    //base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Able to fix this using helper value.

```
private double _oldValue;
protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
{
    _oldValue = oldValue; // store previous values so we can later fix issues

    base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
}
```

And in the calculation

```
// if (newMaximum < Value) // this will never be true because if value is bigger than newMaximum 
                           // slider cuts the Value before we reach here.

if (newMaximum > Value) // in case newMaximum was bigger than value
                        // that means we are safe to use original value
                        // if newMaximum is equal to Value that means 
                        // slider has possibly changed the value we should use _oldValue
    _oldValue = Value;

Value = _oldValue * (newMaximum - Minimum) / (oldMaximum - Minimum);
```

I did this and the slider keeps the ratio. no matter how fast I change maximum or minimum. the results are correct.  surprisingly there is no race condition here.

The same logic goes for fixing ration when minimum boundary changes.

```
if (newMinimum < Value)
    _oldValue = Value;

Value = _oldValue * (Maximum - newMinimum) / (Maximum - oldMinimum);
```